# Цикл должен реагировать на значение в тестовом поле(Entry).Tkinter в Python

Tags: python, циклы, tkinter

Всем привет.Пишу безобидный спамер на Python 3.9.2.Уже проработал интерфейс.Но теперь мне нужно чтобы значение,введенное в текстовом поле Entry применялось к циклу.Например я ввожу 4,и цикл for i in range(a):выводит мне на экран a окон. Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import*#importing module
```

```py
a=Entry


def start(event):
    label["text"]=a.get()#add function

Window1= Tk()
Window1.title("SpamEngiene v0.1.0")#Changing the title
Window1.geometry("1000x700")
Window1["bg"] = "gray22"#set the settings f the window

Window1.minsize(500, 350)#set the minimum window values
Window1.maxsize(1000, 700)#set the maximum window values

label=Label(Window1, text="Welcome to the SpamEhgiene", bg="grey22", fg="white", font="Calibri 20")
label.place(x=200, y=50)#create text
label.pack()#pack text 

entry1=Entry(Window1, bg="white", width="30", font="Calibri 13")
entry1.place(x=50, y=100)

but=Button(Window1, text="Ok")
but.place(x=170, y=130)
but.bind("<Button-1>", start)

print(a)
```

Comment: Версия пайтона в данном случае не имеет значения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете доступаться на прямую к полю ввода.

Замените вашу функцию `start` на:

```
def start(_):
    for i in range(int(entry1.get())):
        print(i)  # тут вы должны вызвать "Окно"
```

Comment: Эндрю,спасибо вам огромное!Ваше решение работает!